# Jmeter - How to create re-usable jsr223 sampler

Tags: jmeter

For the purpose of my test, I want to create a re-usable jsr223 sampler (JSR223 Assertion) sampler, so I can just reuse it in multiple HTTP requests. What is the easiest way to achieve that using JMeter, rather than duplication of the same code?

Comment: Your question isn't clear, but you can use same Script file

Answer (score 0):

If you place an [Assertion](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#assertions) at the same level as [Samplers](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#samplers) - it will be applied to all of them:

[image]

More information: [JMeter Scoping Rules - The Ultimate Guide](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-scoping-rules-the-ultimate-guide)